# My token expired on my dart code and I'm not sure how to refresh it

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class UserClient {
  final _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: BaseUrl));
  DataService _dataService = DataService();

  Future<AuthResponse?> Login(LoginStructure user) async {
    try {
      var response = await _dio.post("/login",
          data: {"username": user.username, "password": user.password});

      var data = response.data['data'];
      var authResponse = new AuthResponse(data['userId'], data['token']);

      if (authResponse.token != null) {
        await _dataService.AddItem("token", authResponse.token);
      }

      return authResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<List<User>?> GetUserAsync() async {
    try {
      var token = await _dataService.TryGetItem("token");
      if (token != null) {
        var response = await _dio.get("/GetUsers",
            options: Options(headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
            }));

        List<User> users = new List.empty(growable: true);

        if (response != null) {
          for (var user in response.data) {
            users.add(User(user["_id"], user["Username"], user["Password"],
                user["Email"], user["AuthLevel"]));
          }

          return users;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }

}`
```

Here is my code for this class and now I'm getting a 401 error and it won't allow me to log back into the API. How do I refresh my token to allow me access again?

Just been messing around but don't have a great idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function to refresh the access token:

```
Future<String> refreshToken() async {
  // Perform a request to the refresh token endpoint and return the new access token.
  // You can replace this with your own implementation.
  return 'your_new_access_token';
}
```

Next, add an interceptor to the DIO instance:

```
dio.interceptors.add(
  InterceptorsWrapper(
    onRequest: (options, handler) {
      // Add the access token to the request header
      options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer your_access_token';
      return handler.next(options);
    },
    onError: (DioError e, handler) async {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
        // If a 401 response is received, refresh the access token
        String newAccessToken = await refreshToken();

        // Update the request header with the new access token
        e.requestOptions.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $newAccessToken';

        // Repeat the request with the updated header
        return handler.resolve(await dio.fetch(e.requestOptions));
      }
      return handler.next(e);
    },
  ),
);
```

With this interceptor in place, your application will automatically refresh the access token and retry requests whenever a 401 response is received.